# How and to what extent does the US constitution force state legislatures to be democratic?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, constitutional-law

So there are a lot of provisions related to voting on a federal level, e.g. the electoral college is described in article II (interestingly, clause 2 says: "Each State shall appoint, *in such Manner as the Legislature thereof may direct*, a Number of Electors […]") and the 17th amendment prescribes the direct election of senators in each state ("[…] two Senators from each State, elected by the people […]"). Now what about the state legislatures themselves? Is there some provision I missed?

In short: Could Hawaii become a somewhat absolutistic kingdom again and still remain a U.S. state? ;)

Comment: This seems a little broad, but it's really interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Article IV, Section 4 says this:

> The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of Government

That would mean no state can be a kingdom.

**PS in response to comments:** This section does not mean the federal government is guaranteeing to the states that the **federal** government will be republican in form; rather the federal government is required to guarantee that the **state** governments will be republican in form.  That is done when Congress looks over a proposed state constitution before admitting a proposed new state to the Union.  That has not always been done, since in particular it was not done in Kentucky.  (On February 4, 1791, Congress passed an act saying the district of Kentucky in the state of Virginia would be admitted as a new state, of course with the consent of the Virginia legislature that had been expressed in 1789, but would not be admitted until almost 16 more months passed.  The politicians of Kentucky had requested the long delay so they could use the time to negotiate compromises on details of their state constitution, which hadn't been written yet.  That was the first time Congress passed a law admitting a new state, but because of the delay, Kentucky became the 15th state rather than the 14th (Vermont is the 14th).)

Comment: Ah OK, so this also refers to all state governments and not just the federal one? Because otherwise I read it as "this union is democratic, but not necessarily its members".

Comment: @phk : I'm not sure I understand your comment.  The _federal_ government will guarantee the _states_ a republican form of government.  So federal and state are involved in different ways in this section.  That the _federal_ government will be republiccan in form is spelled out in detail in Articles I through III.

Comment: True, makes a lot of sense. Also, what would the federal government guaranteeing ***to each state*** to be republican itself even mean, either it is (to all), or it isn't.

Comment: @phk : Article IV, Section 4 does not say the federal government will guarantee that the federal government will be republican in form; rather it says that the federal government will guarantee that the _state_ governments will be republican in form.  As far as I know the only way in which that has been done is that when new states are admitted to the Union, Congress looks at the proposed state constitution to see if it is republican in form.  Congress has not actually done that in every case; in particular it was not done with Kentucky.

Comment: And Rhode Island which is then led to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorr_Rebellion.

Comment: [It is probably worth mentioning that SCOTUS has held that this clause is a "political question", and so non-justiciable.](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artIV-S4-1-1-2/ALDE_00001174/). It's all left to Congress, and when appropriate the President, to decide.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Why, then, are states no longer allowed to have a house of state government which e.g. grants representation on a per-county, rather than per-person, basis in a manner analogous to the US Senate?

Comment: @supercat That was on 14th amendment equal protection grounds (1 person, 1 vote), not republican government grounds.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: How does "representation" equate to "protection" when applied to persons who are ineligible to vote?  If issues regarding state government organization are outside federal jurisdiction as you claim, that decision should be recognized as a judicial usurpation of power which is binding upon the actual parties, but nobody else.

Comment: @supercat Because the constitution has many clauses and provisions which are held in balance and many of them overlap and some can be brought to bear in situations where others cannot.  SCOTUS cannot decide if a state government qualifies as "republican" or not, but it can decide if the system of government adheres to the other clauses and provisions of the constitution which are justiciable, including the 14th amendment's equal protection clause.